# Find the match extract next n chars but exclude a match itself

Tags: regex

I am not a regex savvy so my question may seem simple. How do you extract hours and minutes from a string like this:

```
2013-12-03T10:45:33-07:00
```

So I just want to get 10:45 from the above string and ignore the rest.

I tried `/[0-2][0-9]:[0-5][0-9]/` but that gives me: 10:45 as well as 07:00

Also tried `/[T][0-2][0-9]:[0-5][0-9]/` , but this gives me T10:45

I tried excluding 'T' by using a ^ anchor `[^T][ ][ ]:[ ][ ]` but this gave me -07:00 !

I thought about searching for the first occurrence of ':' but I don't know how to extract 2 digits before and after ':' and include the ':' itself.

Any help with a comment would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What language do you use?

Comment: It looks like you're only interested in the first match of `/[0-2][0-9]:[0-5][0-9]/`, so why are you applying it twice?

Comment: The regex will be used in jmeter which is Java.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a [positive lookbehind](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) for this:

```
/(?<=T)\d{2}:\d{2}/
```

What this essentially means it that we're matching two digits followed by a colon followed by 2 digits, but they MUST have a "T" in front. Do not, however, add this to the match as lookaheads/behinds are not matched.

[**DEMO**](http://regex101.com/r/yR0hH5)

`[^T]` means "any character that isn't `T`", which is why it didn't work.

---

JS regex does not support lookaheads/behinds ([**see?**](http://regex101.com/r/rK0hX7)), but you can simply create a matching group using `/T(\d{2}:\d{2})/` and then match `[1]`:

```
var timeString = '2013-12-03T10:45:33-07:00';
var time = timeString.match(/T(\d{2}:\d{2})/)[1];
console.log(time); //10:45
```

Comment: +1 although I would remove the slashes - they have nothing to do with regex; they are used by some languages to delimit regex

Comment: @Bohemian I simply replicated OP's style of showing regex. :-)

Comment: Great, thanks a lot. But I am using this in jmeter and for some reason it doesn't seem to work in jmeter. Also it doesn't work on some other regex tester sites, but it clearly works on regex101.com

Comment: So I figured the example works in Pearl and PHP but it does not work in JavaScript. How could I make it work in JavaScript and Java?

Comment: @user3062521 Check my edit. JS regex does not have negative/positive lookaheads/behinds

Answer (score 1):

A simple way to extract without heavy regex knowledge would be to do something like

```
foo = "2013-12-03T10:45:33-07:00"
(hours,minutes,junk) = foo.split ":"
hours =~ s/*(\d\d)$/$1/
```

so now you have

**hours** and **minutes** available for use

Comment: Thanks, this is the approach I may need to write a jmeter Bean shell script to do this since positive lookbehind regex doesn't seem to work in jmeter. Actually the whole string looks like this:

Comment: "current-time":"2013-12-03T15:03:30-07:00"

Comment: Glad to help, As long as you know ahead of time the format of your string, my approach works... so with current_time...etc the split would have to have an extra field. `(bah,hours,minutes,junk) =` et al...

Comment: Rather then doing a string split, I did substring like this hours = foo.substring(10,15)  no regex.

Comment: Whatever works best for you is right. For me, messing around with counting characters and making sure index positions are right is something I decided long ago made me unhappy, hence I avoid substring if I can at all help it.